# Is there any way of adapting this name-generating loop to run for a minimum number of seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code (which has some Frog VLE API code in it; hopefully that's not too relevant) to pick a random student from a list.

This works well, but sometimes - given its random nature - it only runs for a very brief period of time. Would it be possible to loop this a number of times first, to ensure that it runs for X period of time as a minimum?

```
var Count = 0;

/* construct the array of people */
for (var i in data.users) {
    for (var n = 0; n < data.users[i].Quantity; n++) {
        var TempObj = { 'Count' : Count, 'Student_ID' : i, 'Student_Name' : data.users[i].Student_Name };
        RewardPurchases.PurchasesArray[Count] = TempObj;
        Count++;
    }
}
```

... more code here, nothing relevant to the way the script works ...

```
$('button#random').click( function() {

    /* first things first, play a drum-roll when the button is clicked! */
    $('embed').remove();
    $('body').append('<embed src="/user/74/177499.wav" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="true">');

    /* take the RewardPurchases.PurchasesArray and sort it so that there's no particular order */
    RewardPurchases.PurchasesArray.sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random()})

    /* remove the winner class for consecutive re-rolls */
    $display.removeClass( "winner" );
    $display.addClass( "spinner" );

    /* determine the number of people in the array and calculate a random winner */
    var total = RewardPurchases.PurchasesArray.length,
        selected = Math.floor( Math.random() * total ),
        i = 0;

    /* work out how long each name should appear for, dependent upon how many people are in the array */
    var timeout = ( 15000 / total );

    /* run through the array of people ... */
    for (i=0; i<total; i++) {

        setTimeout((function(i){
            return function(){
                console.log( "timeout", i );

                /* ... if the person in the array is a valid person! then display their name */
                if (typeof RewardPurchases.PurchasesArray[i] === 'object' && typeof RewardPurchases.PurchasesArray[i] !== null) {
                    $display.text( "[" + RewardPurchases.PurchasesArray[i].Count + "] " + RewardPurchases.PurchasesArray[i].Student_Name.toUpperCase() );

                    /* if we encounter the winner, play a cheering wav and change the class of the display so that they appear in big, bold, red text */
                    if( i === selected ) {
                        $('embed').remove();
                        $('body').append('<embed src="/user/74/177086.wav" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="false">');

                       $display.addClass( "winner" );
                    }
                }
            };
        }(i)), i*timeout);

        /* if the winner has been found, break the loop */
        if( i === selected ) {
            break;
        }
    }
} );
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Could you explain what the code does?

Comment: Hi @AlexDev I've updated my code with comments about how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this :

```
function doforsec(msec, func) {
    var curDate = new Date().getTime();
    while ((new Date().getTime() - curDate) < msec) {
        func();
    }
}
doforsec(200, function() {
    console.log(new Date().getSeconds())
});​
```

This executes the function given to doforsec again and again until the timeperiod specified (in milliseconds) is over. (first i had seconds, but i think milliseconds will be better)

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7LMkP/1/)

Comment: I've tried to use this, but when I try to replicate the `for` loop I have in my original code (minus the selection bit, so that the loop just goes round a few times), it simply doesn't work - nothing appears to happen.

Comment: I took your for loop above with an sample Students Array and wrapped the while loop around ` `
Look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7DRuH/) `  `  
and change the `msec` variable, it runs for the time specified

Answer (score 0):

After     var timeout = ( 15000 / total ); insert the following, and remove the line for (i=0; i

```
var totalTime = 2000;
var timeOut= Math.Ceiling(totalTime/timeout);
var timesToDisplay = totalTime / timeOut;
var currentDisplay = 0;
for (currentDisplay = 0; currentDisplay < timesToDisplay; currentDisplay++) {

    i = currentDisplay % total;
```

Comment: Hi Alex. That would work, to an extent, but it would simply lengthen the time each name was displayed on the screen before the winner was picked. This will be my "fall back approach", but I would rather that the system "looped once more" or something instead if possible.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question then. Could you explain what the code does?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts AlexDev but that doesn't appear to have changed anything that I can see? When I try with 2 students, it takes less than a second to complete.

Comment: @dunc this will only work for higher values of totalTime. Try setting it to 15000 or more

Answer (score 0):

Because my deadline for this is.. well, around 8 hours from posting this.. I've decided to re-write the script and use a jQuery plugin:

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(from, to) {
    var rest = this.slice((to || from) + 1 || this.length);
    this.length = from < 0 ? this.length + from : from;
    return this.push.apply(this, rest);
};

$(document).ready(function(){

        var staff = [ 'hardcoded', 'list', 'of', 'staff', 'members' ];

        $('button#start').click( function() {
        var $display = $('#display'),
            $results = $('#results table');
        $display.removeClass( "winner" );
        $display.addClass( "spinner" );

        var counter = 0,            
            rand = 0,
            run_time = 10,
            delay = ( run_time * 100 ) / staff.length,
            loop_number = 5,
            max_count = staff.length * loop_number;

        $display.doTimeout( 'loop', delay, function() {
            counter++;
            var newRand = Math.floor( Math.random() * staff.length );
            if ( rand === newRand ) {
                rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * staff.length );
            } else {
                rand = newRand;
            }

            $(this).text( staff[rand] );

            if ( counter < max_count ) { return true; }
            else {
                $('#results tr:last').after('<tr><td class="number">' + staff.length + '</td><td>' + staff[rand] + '</td></tr>');
                staff.remove( rand );
            }
        });

        $display.doTimeout( 'class', max_count * delay, function() {
            $display.removeClass( "spinner" );
            $display.addClass( "winner" );
        });
    });

});
```